# In Doctrine and mySql, how to query records that do not have dates

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

In Doctrine QueryBuilder, I want to find all records where a date field does not have a real date.  I have found, though, that the date `'0000-00-00'` is NULL, and it's also NOT NULL.  In other words,

```
$qb->select('t')
    ->from(myTable, 't')
    ->andWhere ... some condition...
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNull('t.myDate'));
```

and

```
$qb->select('t')
    ->from(myTable, 't')
    ->andWhere ... some condition...
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNotNull('t.myDate'));
```

both include records where the value in `myDate` is `'0000-00-00'`.

I've considered doing something like,

```
$qb->select('t')
    ->from(myTable, 't')
    ->andWhere ... some condition...
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('t.myDate','?1'))
    ->setParameter(1, '0000-00-00');
```

but 1) that only picks up the dates that are '0000-00-00' and misses the dates that are actually null; and 2) I understand that '0000-00-00' doesn't always equal '0000-00-00'; that even though my column is a DATE type, the $qb->expr()->eq( ... ) syntax might have to include TIME characters (00:00:00).

It would be cool if Doctrine had something like notWhere:

```
$qb->select('t')
    ->from(myTable, 't')
    ->andWhere ... some condition...
    ->butDefinitelyNotWhere($qb->expr()->isNull('t.myDate'));
```

because instead of finding all of the records where the date is NOT NULL, it finds what I'm looking for: all of the records that do not belong to the set where the date "is" NULL.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `->andWhere($qb->expr()->neq('t.myDate', ':nullDate'))->setParameter('nullDate', '0000-00-00')` ?

Comment: I said in the question that I had considered that option, but that it misses the dates that are actually null (empty).

Answer (score 0):

I did not try, but maybe with something like:

```
 ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNotNull('WEEK(t.myDate)'));
```

Comment: gives `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 79: Error: Expected known function, got 'WEEK'`

Comment: Same error.  Writing a query with `WEEK('myDate') is not null` in mySql works there, but I can't get Doctrine to produce a working query.

Comment: To make `WEEK (...)` work you need a [User defined function](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html#date-diff)